# problem with <afxcontrolbars.h> in VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I cant figure out why my program refuse to build. it throws the error message - 
stdafx.h(36): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'afxcontrolbars.h': No such file or directory
I am using windows xp and vs2010, can you help me with that?
thank you on advance.

Comment: That's part of MFC, you may need to reinstall or repair Visual Studio if you are missing that header.

Comment: I first installed VS 2010 and then VS 2008 could this be an issue? if I reinstall VS 2010 this problem will be solved?

Comment: Potentially, I have 2005, 2008, and 2010 on my machine but I also installed them in that order and MFC etc is fine and dandy across the various versions. I'd certainly try re-installing first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you migrate a project from VC2008 to VC2010, make sure to change 'Platform Toolset' (in 'Configuration Properties' -> 'General') from 'V90' to 'V100'.